# Clicking polygon in OpenLayers map and zooming, centering polygon in map?

Tags: openlayers

I click on the map on a polygon and I'd like to zoom the map and center it around the polygon.

We have done so until now:

```
map.on ('click', function (e) {
     console.log (s);
    // coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    
   

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel (e.pixel, function (feature) {return feature;});

    var coordinate = e.coordinate;
    var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS (ol.proj.transform (coordinate, 'EPSG: 31700', 'EPSG: 3857'));
    
    _myStroke = new ol.style.Stroke ({
       color: 'yellow',
       width: 4
    });
    
    _myFill = new ol.style.Fill ({
       color: 'rgba (255,0,0,1.0)'
    });
    
    selected_polygon_style = new ol.style.Style ({
       stroke: _myStroke,
       fill: _myFill
     });

   feature.setStyle (selected_polygon_style);
   
   map.fitBounds (e.layer.getBounds ());
)}
```

I'm trying to do this with this code line taken from an example here:

map.fitBounds (e.layer.getBounds ());

But it is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'getBounds' of undefined
```

And I do not know what it could be.

Comment: `fitBounds` is used in Google maps.  In OpenLayers to fit the map to your polygon use  `map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry());`

Comment: Yes running corectly, thanks Mike!

Answer (score 3):

This sould do it:

```
map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry())
```

You can also make it animated:

```
map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry(), { duration: 1000 })
```

More info about the available options here: [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View.html#~FitOptions](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View.html#%7EFitOptions)